# Regarding the domain of $f(x) = \sqrt[4] {\log_2 (\tan x)}$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I'm having some trouble finding the domain of the equation in the title.

I know that $\log_2 (\tan x) \gt 0$, which gives $\tan x \gt 2$ when simplified.

However how should I get rid of the $tan$ as to restrict my domain?

Also, does the fourth root in there changes anything? It isn't a cubic root, so it should behave just like a normal square root, where the domain must be $\ge 0$. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Do you know how to solve $\tan x=2$? You are right about the root.

Comment: No... I suppose I want to transform it to radians, but I don't know how to do that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want $\log_2(\tan x) \geq 0$ since there is a $4$-th root.

Now $\log_2(\tan x) \geq 0$ is equivalent to $\tan x \geq 1$ which has solutions
$$
\arctan 1+ n\pi \leq x < \frac{\pi}{2} + n\pi \\
\frac{\pi}{4}+ n\pi \leq x < \frac{\pi}{2} + n\pi
$$

Comment: Would you tell me the mathematical procedure you used to get from $\tan x$ to the two final equations? I wanted to practice it a bit.

Comment: You have to look at goniometric inequalities.. one way to solve them is graphically

Comment: I think you meant to say "trigonometric inequalities"? Anyways, it does seem to be it. Thanks!